# Ubuntu20.04 stuck at Finished Detect the availa... deal with any system changes

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I got "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running." after my ubuntu kernal update.
I tried reboot to fix this, but my screen resolution is locked in 1024x768 (4:3). I tried cmd "sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 535.xxx.xx" to fix the nvidia driver.

[Ubuntu20.04 stuck at Finished Detect the availa... deal with any system changes for several days after reboot：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDOxI.jpg)
Who can tell me what to do next to fix the system?